# Set spinner inital value from database and spinner items are from array string in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner in which I have two values "AM" and "PM". Spinner values are from a string array. the array name is "ampm".But I want to load the initial value of the spinner from the database value. that means if the saved value in the database is pm then initially PM will be shown in the spinner and on click, it will show the other options that are "AM". Need help in this regard. I have done the following code.

```
 final Spinner ampmspin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ampm);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ampm_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.am_pm, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);


    ampm_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ampmspin.setPrompt("Select Shift");

    ampmspin.setAdapter(
            new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                    ampm_adapter, R.layout.shift_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                    // R.layout.contact_spinner_nothing_selected_dropdown, // Optional
                    this));



    ampmspin.setSelected(false);  // must
    ampmspin.setSelection(0,true);  //must
   ampmspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below function after setting adapter to spinner.

```
 private static final String TIME_AM = "AM";
 private static final String TIME_PM = "PM";

private void setSpinnerValue(String dataBaseValue)
    {
        if(dataBaseValue.equalsIgnoreCase(TIME_AM)) // IF Data base value is AM select position as 0
        {
            ampmspin.setSelection(0);
        }
        else if(dataBaseValue.equalsIgnoreCase(TIME_PM)) // IF Data base value is PM select position as 1
        {
            ampmspin.setSelection(1);
        }
        else // IF no data in database then we need keep 0 as default
        {
            ampmspin.setSelection(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the value from data base and find the item in spinner list and set to spinner

```
String st_name = document.getString("State");  //getting value from database  
int Hold = dataAdapter.getPosition(st_name);//finding value in spinner list
spin.setSelection(Hold);//setting spinner
```